# List as part of an enum's values

Tags: java, list, arraylist, enums

Hi so I have an enum in which I want to store a number of singular integer values and one String.

It would appear something like the below:

```
EXAMPLE(15, 16, 17, 90, "INVALID")
```

The issue is I want the fourth Integer to by an ArrayList of integers.

```
EXAMPLE(-1, -1, -1, (ArrayList of Integers), "INVALID")
```

The reason for this is the fourth element refers to Object Ids and for any one Enum there can be between 0 and 5 Object Ids.

I know I can add the ArrayList as part of the constructor parameters I just don't know how to add the individual lists to each Enum constant.

Comment: Something like `EXAMPLE(1, 2, 3, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3,2,1)), "ABC")`?

Comment: Or just `EXAMPLE(1, 2, 3, Arrays.asList(3,2,1), "ABC")`. It doesn't seem like a good idea to have an enum constant with a field that's a mutable ArrayList.

Comment: If the lists can be immutable, you can use `List.of(1,2,3)` as the argument to the enum type.